# Where does serverside meteor code run when deployed via cordova?

Tags: javascript, mobile, web-applications, meteor, architecture

I was thinking about how to architect my project. Im making a meteor webapplication for the normal browser, which will be a 'eventmanager'. which will be used to make events, that a seperate meteor app will then connect to via ddp, signup for the events etc.

So im obviously using DDP to connect the two apps but suddenly i was wondering where meteor places the serverside code in a mobile application, since this is a huge deal, a mobileapp has to work even when not on the internet, so i thouth that it would be logical that some of the serverside rendering was happening offline on the phone, and if thats not the case, well then i would have to seperate my app somehow, into something that renders with the localstorage data if not connected to the internet & i would have to sync the two applications databases + local storage.

Im thinking that the serverside code does run on the mobile phone, it just feels counterintuitive that each mobile phone has its own 'server'.

thanks for any help :)

Comment: I could be wrong but im pretty sure the Cordova app is just a wrapper, so there would be no server side code run on the phone (why would there ever be?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cordova is just a wrapper. It works just like any other browser. While it does provide API access to the hardware, the app itself is not native. It's a hybrid app platform.

The client side runs within the app container (Cordova) and communicates with the server portion over sockets.

Comment: Oh..Sorry @RamsayLanier. I didn't see that you had commented already. DOH! :)